# REGEXP in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a database of all english language words. I want to find regular expression for particular alphabets. like for example if i ask for the regular expression for "eta", it should return all the words who have 'e','a' and 't' in any combination. but when I run the following code

```
SELECT word FROM wordlist
WHERE 
word REGEXP 'eta';
```

it return words like 'beta,caretake,detach etc....'
how to use regexp in its true spirit in mysql.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  word
FROM    wordlist
WHERE   word REGEXP 'e'
        AND word REGEXP 'a'
        AND word REFEXP 't'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT word FROM wordlist WHERE word REGEXP '(e|t|a)'
```

Comment: it even matches a single letter.

Comment: actually my aim is that it should return those words which have these three alphabets. it should not match the 'head' because in this word t is not present. but it should match 'teach' because it has all three words. thanks for comments guys :)